# What does the "D" symbol mean on this instrument approach chart?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, faa, aeronautical-charts

What does the "**D**" symbol mean on this approach plate in the airport diagram section (bottom left of plate)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

> A [D] symbol is shown to indicate runway declared distance information available, see appropriate Chart Supplement for distance information.

That's from the [FAA Aeronautical Chart User's Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) page 124. The wording was different in the 12th edition, it used the A/FD terminology:

[image]